# visual basic: finding a matching string

Tags: database, visual-studio-2010

I'm using VB 2010 Express to access a database in .mdb format. 
I want to find the row that contains a specific string of characters and numbers, so I wrote this while loop. I'm using If statement to make sure the loop doesn't exceed the maximum rows ( MaxRows ) and throw an error. The result it keeps giving : " No record found " even though string does exist in the database. What am I doing wrong?

notes: inc is used to increment the row. message box is only to view the variables values

Code:

```
    Dim lpn As String
    Dim lpn2 As String


    inc = 0

    lpn = TextBox5.Text

    lpn2 = ds.Tables("RegisteredCarsDataSet").Rows(inc).Item(7)

    MsgBox(lpn & " " & lpn2 & " ") 

    While lpn <> lpn2

        If inc <> MaxRows - 1 Then
            inc = inc + 1
            lpn2 = ds.Tables("RegisteredCarsDataSet").Rows(inc).Item(7)

            MsgBox(lpn & " " & lpn2)
        Else
            MsgBox("No record found.")
            Exit While
        End If
    End While

    TextBox1.Text = ds.Tables("RegisteredCarsDataSet").Rows(inc).Item(1)
    TextBox2.Text = ds.Tables("RegisteredCarsDataSet").Rows(inc).Item(2)
    TextBox3.Text = ds.Tables("RegisteredCarsDataSet").Rows(inc).Item(3)
    TextBox4.Text = ds.Tables("RegisteredCarsDataSet").Rows(inc).Item(4)
    ComboBox1.Text = ds.Tables("RegisteredCarsDataSet").Rows(inc).Item(5)
    ComboBox2.Text = ds.Tables("RegisteredCarsDataSet").Rows(inc).Item(6)
    TextBox5.Text = ds.Tables("RegisteredCarsDataSet").Rows(inc).Item(7)
```

Comment: Offtopic, but aren't you considered issuing direct sql command like "select * from mytable where myfield like 'mystring'"? Or at least issuing find command on recordset with similar condition?

Comment: I'm not familiar with sql, this first time I use databases. I used the only way I know. But if you know a better way, please inform me.

Comment: Is it correct to say that if I use the " select * from mytable where myfield like 'mystring'" that I should save the result in a new dataset?

Comment: IMO yes, but actually I have not directly worked with VB datasets and thereby I can't give good guidance. (That's one reason why I only commented here.)